How to merge different models in Django?
I have huge concern about merge two or more models in Django.
First, there are 9 models in models.py. (just structure)
model A   (fields: user, AA(foreign key), created_at)
model AA  (fields: user, title, content)
model AAA (fields: AA(foreign key), theme_name)

model B   (fields: user, BB(foreign key), created_at)
model BB  (fields: user, title, content)
model BBB (fields: BB(foreign key), theme_name)

model C   (fields: user, CC(foreign key), created_at)
model CC  (fields: user, title, content)
model CCC (fields: CC(foreign key), theme_name)

And I want to merge model A, model B, model C, ordered by 'created_at' with Pagination and filter(with theme_name).
I searched for how to merge, but there seemed to be no way other than using annotate to align and merge all types and quantities of fields.
However, when additional models created later, if I use annotate at that time, it is expected that the annotated fields will increase too much and it will take more time.
What should I do?

Since you've tagged Django REST Framework, I assume you mean merging them for serialization somehow..? Could you show a more concrete example than A/AA/AAA?

@AKX Yes. I thought that A.union(B, C) is appropriate answer and serialize it in aspect of model A, but it does not efficient answer.

@AKX I don't know if it'll help, but I'll give you a more detailed answer.
Model AA, Model BB, and Model CC are three boards and have different characteristics, so they are separated.
Models AAA, BBB, and CCC are fields that connect the themes of AAA, BBB, and CC. (many to many relationships)
And models A, B, and C are models that each user added models AA, BB, and CC to their favorite.
I want to look up all the posts the user has added to the favorite, regardless of the type, and sort them in the order created_at.

It might be hard to make this efficient with this database design.  You could use union, or maybe an SQL view that combines the three tables, but depending on your RDBMS, those may have limitations wrt. ordering and limits/offsets.
